# Spring Boot JPA Many to one - Fetch data based on associated model condition

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two models - **Gallery** and **Category**.

> **Category** has many **Gallery**  - `@OneToMany`
>
> **Gallery** belongs to **Gallery** - `@ManyToOne`

**Gallery.java**

```
@Entity(name="Gallery")
public class Gallery {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="category_id")
    private Category category;

    /* other code */
}
```

**Category.java**

```
@Entity(name="Category")
@Table(name="categories")
public class Category {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="category")
    private Gallery gallery;
    /* other code */
}
```

**GalleryRepository.java**

```
@Repository("galleryRepository")
public interface GalleryRepository extends JpaRepository<Gallery, Long>, SiteInfoCustomRepository {

}
```

> **Question**: How to fetch gallery data based on category title? I tried **EntityManager** and **JOIN query** but it's not returning in desired format.

GalleryService.java

```
@Override
public List<Gallery> getGallery(String cat) {
      // this works fine, fetches gallery and associated category
      galleryRepository.findAll();

      // I want to fetch gallery data which matches a particular category title

}
```

Comment: have you tried findAllByCategoryName in your repository ?

Comment: Category "name" is present in Category model, not Gallery model. Is it possible to fetch by Category "name" from GalleryRepository?

Comment: Yes you can fetch based on properties of the associated entities

Comment: `findAllByCategoryName ` method isn't available by default. In which Repository will I need to mentioned it? And do I need to mention anything else. Will be helpful if you could share the code. Thanks!

Comment: OneToMany association should be a collection.. isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I've changed it. It will be a Set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to declare the method in your repository and spring will create the query for you.

Spring deduce the query just from the name of the method, if you want to get all gallery by category name declare it like this

```
@Repository("galleryRepository")
public interface GalleryRepository extends JpaRepository<Gallery, Long>, 
     SiteInfoCustomRepository {
    List<Gallery> findAllByCategoryName(String categoryName);
}
```

The you can call this interface from your service for example:

```
@Service
public class GalleryService {

    @Autowired
    GalleryRepository galleryRepository;

    public List<Gallery> getGalleriesByCategoryName(String name) {
        return galleryRepository.findAllByCategoryName(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, so simple. Worked like a charm :) Thanks a lot, buddy!